# Error in rendering the Rmarkdown document

Tags: r-markdown

While rendering the rmarkdown document, I am getting the error such as:
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Execution halted.

This error gets generated after I press knit to HTML option.

I tried installing the R and RStudio again, with the latest version. However, I am getting the same error again. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Can you show the code in your markdown document. The yaml at the top and the options in each code chunk are probably where this is happening

Comment: This is the code chunk:  ---
title: "R Notation"
author: "Siddharth"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---